# Is there a an app for recording voice notes that syncs to cloud storage?

Tags: notes, voice-recording

I have been using [Note Everything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything&hl=en) for making text and voice notes.

However, the problem with it is that it stores everything locally, and if the phone dies, like mine recently did, I lose all the notes. It does have a backup function, but I have to take steps to save the backup files which I often forget to do.

What I really want is an application that will always sync every voice and text note with a server somewhere, so that it doesn't matter if the phone is destroyed.

I do not need to share these notes with anyone else, and I would rather that whatever service I used the default was that all my notes were private. However, if I could also access my notes via the web, that would be ideal. Critically, though, it needs to have both **voice** and **text**.

Are there any applications like that?

Comment: We really prefer questions that ask about a problem to be solved ("How can I do X?") rather than those where a solution is already determined (an app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote). It features cloud sync and it lets you access your notes from almost all platform. You can create audio notes directly from homescreen using its widget, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Catch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threebanana.notes) Notes for this functionality: notes saved offline and synced, when internet connected (and some notes I'm editing from my PC via web browser, their synced later).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure *Note Everything* to do regular backups of all your notes (they will be stored on SD card then). If you additionally want to have those data sync'd with "the cloud", you might want to take a look at specific synchronization apps, like e.g. [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). This way you can keep the app you are already used to (and which is wonderful, by the way -- I use it myself), and still have your data secured on a) SD card and b) some other machine (be it "the cloud", or your local computer at home).

Answer (score 0):

Evernote is the most versatile you'll find. You can save and sync voice, text, images, and almost everything else, all for free. (Providing you use under 60mb per month, and even using it frequently as I do, I rarely exceed 10mb)

Evernote also crosses platforms and will work on your android, windows ios and other devices, and allows for web access for any other device with internet.

Comment: Evernote was already suggested in [another answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/33683/267).

Answer (score 0):

I use the notes recorder app. It's free and does the job as an audio recorder well. All sound files are immediately uploaded into the cloud where it becomes accessible on other platforms.

- [Record  - Android Apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dezainwerkz.sound_recorder)
- [Record  - Web App](http://www.notesrecorder.com/)